# SML Counting calls and activation records, efficiency of an iterative algorithm

Tags: algorithm, runtime, sml

This is my assignment, called Time and Space Requirements.

http://prnt.sc/aasnn4

NOTE: The tutor I was working with said that he didn't see a usage case, so we used a list of (1,2,3,4,5,6).

```
exception Empty;
exception Empty;
fun middle1(l) =
     let fun len(nil)  = 0
           | len(x::l) = 1+len(l)
         and get(n, nil)  = raise Empty
           | get(n, x::l) = if n=1 then x else get(n-1,l)
        in
           get((len(l) div 2)+1, l)
        end;
val middle1 = fn : 'a list -> 'a

middle1([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
val it = 4 : int
```

So far, what we have is:

a. 2 calls to the `len` function and 2 activation records

b. 4 calls to the `get` function and 4 activation records

c. We believe it's more efficient. Only a single activation record could be used, since it could be reused, and assignment can be used to change the values of function parameters for each call.

**Basically, are we going in the right direction?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.